# Visual Class Properties that provide rendering support

Tags: wpf, properties

What are the properties of the [`Visual`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visual.aspx) class that provide the actual rendering support?

I am trying to understand how rendering works in WPF. Like why we can render a Drawing by itself, since it provides both a geometry a brush and a pen. I am looking at the properties, and trying to make out what they provide at the base level to enable rendering.